# Limma's vennDiagram doesn't plot the values

Tags: r, venn-diagram, limma

The basic vennDiagram plot works very well.
But I'm trying to show the percentage instead of amount like this

```
vennDiagram(vennCounts( df)/5000*100, circle.col = 1:4)
```

It works with 2 and 3 sets: 
[image]

But with 4 and 5 sets the percentages aren't plotted only the labels and the none section:

[image]

Tried these steps:

- round the percentage to 0, 1 and 2
- change the **cex** (text size) argument to smaller

Maybe not enough space?